# How can I get the last number in string by sscanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

If I have:

```
str1 = "str1s2"
str2 = "djfs1d2.3"
```

How can I get the last number in string by sscanf()?

I tried:

```
sscanf(str1, "%*[^0-9]%d", &n1);
sscanf(str2, "%*[^0-9]%d", &n2);
```

But I get only the first number:

```
n1 = 1
n2 = 1
```

Comment: reverse then reverse or loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what reverse?

Comment: If `str3 = "abc1d2e34";` Do you want `34` or `4` as the last "number"?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 34

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `%n` specifier to store the number of characters processed by the scan, you can iterate through the string until scanf fails.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( ) {
    char str2[] = "2to3";
    int span = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int lastvalue = 0;
    int value = 0;

    if ( 1 == sscanf ( &str2[index], "%d%n", &value, &span)) {
        index += span;
        lastvalue = value;
    }
    while ( 1 == sscanf ( &str2[index], "%*[^0-9]%d%n", &value, &span)) {
        index += span;
        lastvalue = value;
    }
    printf ( "last value = %d\n", lastvalue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: great! BUT why don't it work with "2to3" or "2to3-2.7"?

Comment: It prints value = 0

Answer (score 2):

I personally find it to elaborative an error prone to express this solely with a `scanf`-pattern. I'd rather use a separate loop that iterates from the end of the string towards the beginning and positions a pointer right at the last number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// extracts the last positive integral value of string s
// returns...
// on success, the int value scanned
// -1, if the string is null, empty, or not terminated by a number
int extractLastIntegral(const char* s) {
    int value = -1;
    if (s && *s) {  // don't parse null and empty strings
        const char *scanstr = s + strlen(s) - 1;
        while (scanstr > s && isdigit(*(scanstr-1))) {
            scanstr--;
        }
        sscanf(scanstr,"%d", &value);
    }
    return value;
}

int main ( ) {

    const char* teststrings[] = { "str1s2", "djfs1d2.3", "asdf3asd", "asd", "", NULL};
    ;
    for (const char** teststring=teststrings;*teststring;teststring++) {
        printf("string '%s' scans %d\n",*teststring,extractLastIntegral(*teststring));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why `const char *scanstr = *s ? (s + strlen(s) - 1) : s;` ?

Comment: if `s` is an empty string, `s + strlen(s) -1` would lead to `scanptr = s-1`, which is illegal.

Comment: But you are right - it's a bit hard to read. I adapted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate until you fail to get a number. (Probably easier and clearer code to use a character pointer and traverse the string backwards from the end until you find a digit and then continue backwards until you find a non-digit, then scanf from there, though.)

```
char *cp = str1;
int nc;
while(sscanf(cp, "%*[^0-9]%d%n", &n1, &nc) == 1) cp+=nc;
printf("n1: %d\n", n1);
```

Comment: Why the down vote? This is the same as the subsequent/simultaneous answer that was accepted as "the answer".